# Authenticate against Active Directory once counts as two invalid logins

Tags: c#, active-directory, kerberos

Given the following code, with an **incorrect** password:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
                           ContextType.Domain, 
                           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UPN"], 
                           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPUsers"]);
response.IsAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(
                                            request.LoginName, 
                                            request.Password);
```

If we then check

```
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                           principalContext, 
                           IdentityType.SamAccountName, 
                           request.LoginName);
var invalidAttempts = user.BadLogonCount;
```

The value of `invalidAttempts` is 2. In other words, a single attempt to validate credentials is consuming 2 login counts. I am assuming this is occurring because after failing Kerberos it falls back to NTLM.

So the question - is there a way to only validate against Active Directory using the `PrincipalContext`, and only increment bad login count by 1 each time?

Comment: Tried what you said, but at my side I always get increment by 1. Hope you can show more about how you set authentication providers

Comment: Where can I look for more information? I am only assuming it is Kerberos then NTLM that causes 2 login counts, what can I look into to see how my authentication providers are set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, it looks like passing **any** parameter to the `ValidateCredentials` method will solve this. I looked at the decompilation of the assembly, which shows what happens when you don't pass any context options:

```
    try
    {
        this.BindLdap(creds, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);
        this.lastBindMethod = CredentialValidator.AuthMethod.Negotiate;
        return true;
    }
    catch (LdapException ex)
    {
    }

    this.BindLdap(creds, ContextOptions.SimpleBind | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
    this.lastBindMethod = CredentialValidator.AuthMethod.Simple;
    return true;
```

Which by my understanding looks like if I pass no context options it will default to `Negotiate | Singing | Sealing` (as mentioned in documentation), but if that fails it will attempt `SimpleBind | SecureSocketLayer` (not mentioned in documentation). This counts as 2 bad password attempts.

So the solution is to call

```
response.IsAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(
                                        request.LoginName, 
                                        request.Password,
                                        ContextOptions.Negotiate |
                                        ContextOptions.Signing | 
                                        ContextOptions.Sealing);
```

As I don't need to fall back to `SimpleBind`.

Comment: This was driving me nuts.  Your solution worked for me! thanks